# DataGridView ComboBox column dynamic items

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a DataGridView with a ComboBox column. I need it to have different options depending on the row. The values need to be based on the same initial list but filtered to not show any values that are already used.

For example, I have 4 drop down choices: "A", "B", "C" and "D" with 4 rows. Initially no rows are set to any value for the combo box column. The first drop down I click I should see all the choices. Let's say I select "A". Now if I click the drop down on another row I should now only see "B", "C" and "D" because "A" is already used.

I would also like an empty option at the top all the time.

When I try to do this I get a DataRow error. I have tried setting the ComboBox dynamically using CellClick and CellBeginEdit. In both cases I get unexpected behavior. Sometimes already selected values rows will have the value just change because it the previously set value is no longer in the choices. Sometimes nothing happens at all.

Just as a note, I have searched Stack Exchange for a few hours all ready and none of the "solutions" actually work.

EDIT: it appears that by using CellBeginEdit to set the ComboBox items the underlying data is fine. It's just the selected value showing in the combo box that is the issue. If I just select the cell without dropping down the combo box the value does refresh to what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is tricky to get right because the DataGridView tries to cache and reuse the ComboBox in each DataTemplate instantiation.  I have a similar case where I want a "filtering" combobox that filters the list of available choices based on what the user has typed so far into the cell, which is an extreme version of what you are trying to do, so the same trick should work.  The new FilterChanged event can be used to bind to code which can update the combobox list items as needed.  In your cause you could also listen to DataContextChanged event on the FilteringComboBox.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplateSplitPayeeEdit">
    <local:FilteringComboBox Style="{StaticResource GridComboStyle}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding PayeeOrTransferCaption, Mode=TwoWay}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type views:TransactionsView}}, Path=PayeesAndTransferNames}" 
              PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="ComboBoxForPayee_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus"  
              FilterChanged="ComboBoxForPayee_FilterChanged"
             >
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    </local:FilteringComboBox>
</DataTemplate>


    private void ComboBoxForPayee_FilterChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FilteringComboBox combo = sender as FilteringComboBox;
        combo.FilterPredicate = new Predicate<object>((o) => { return o.ToString().IndexOf(combo.Filter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0; });
    }


public class FilteringComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public static RoutedEvent FilterChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("FilterChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(FilteringComboBox));

    public event RoutedEventHandler FilterChanged;

    ListCollectionView view;

    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(System.Collections.IEnumerable oldValue, System.Collections.IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        Filter = null;
        Items.Filter = null;
        this.view = newValue as ListCollectionView;
        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public Predicate<object> FilterPredicate
    {
        get { return view.Filter; }
        set { view.Filter = value; }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {            
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        TextBox edit = this.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", this) as TextBox;
        if (edit != null)
        {
            edit.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(OnEditKeyUp);
        }
    }

    void OnEditKeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox box = (TextBox)sender;
        string filter = box.Text;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
        {
            Items.Filter = null;
        }
        else if (box.SelectionLength < filter.Length)
        {
            if (box.SelectionStart >= 0)
            {
                filter = filter.Substring(0, box.SelectionStart);
            }
            SetFilter(filter);
        }
    }

    public string Filter { 
        get; set; 
    }

    void SetFilter(string text)
    {
        Filter = text;
        var e = new RoutedEventArgs(FilterChangedEvent);
        if (FilterChanged != null)
        {
            FilterChanged(this, e);
        }
        RaiseEvent(e);
    }

    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: It appears that you are using WPF. Any solutions for WinForms?